# Relations: MySQL database view and Yii's CActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a few tables in this app I'm writing. One of them is a view of a table on another database connection:

```
View Staff
staffid,
fullname
<etc>

Table User
user_id
staffid
<etc>
```

Trying to use the `with()` method like this: `User::model()->with('Staff')->findAll()` creates the error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` line 826:

```
825    $pk=array();
826         foreach($this->_pkAlias as $name=>$alias)
827         {
828             if(isset($row[$alias]))
```

The issue is that Yii is expecting a primary key, but views by default do not declare primary keys?

What can I do here?

Comment: Have you defined the primary and foreign keys correctly on the tables?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this issue, the answer is override it in the Model by defining a primary key using the function primaryKey.

```
public function primaryKey() {
    return 'staffid';
}
```

reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6403-how-to-use-cjoinelement-on-a-table-without-primarykey-in-database/page__view__findpost__p__32815